# Fire not rendering in 2.78?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I was following the camp fire tutorial on the blender guru YT channel, and i've run into a problem when I try to render my scene. In the tutorial, it says to switch from GPU to CPU for rendering. I can't even see that option in rendering tab though. The fire works just fine otherwise, and i followed the tutorial exactly. Any ideas why the rendering won't work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: GPU support for smoke/fire has been added since that tutorial was made (at least for CUDA/nvidia). Aside from that, I'm not sure I understand what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The problem is that the fire is showing up when I view my scene in solid or  material mode etc, but not in an actual render. If I try to render it, it just shows me a black circle where my emitter is.

Comment: I don't know this work for you or not, but works for me. Just name the attribute node "flame" and everything renders fine! Regards, Addy

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial, as you can see [here](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-fire-cycles/), is for 2.73, and since then the Blender UI changed a bit, you can find that option in "file=>user preferences=>system" now (it's called "compute device").

You could also download an old 2.73 [from the Blender website](http://download.blender.org/release/), to make it easier to follow the tutorial.

Anyway, remember:

- be sure to use "cycles" render **before** creating the "quick smoke" setup.
- save the file in order to enable the cache settings
- before rendering, run the simulation from the start (frame 1) since it could need recalculations
- if something in the simulation seems to be stuck after some settings change, try also to delete (and thus rebuild) the cache

Also, on the above page you can download a "finished" .blend which could help you understand better.